# Can you use xdebug to debug a microservice type architecture?

Tags: php, debugging, curl, xdebug, microservices

The code base I'm currently working with is one of the most difficult that I have ever worked with. I'm guessing it's based on a microservice type architecture, but badly executed. It consists of a main service and then makes calls via cURL to different separate services and uses the result of those calls. It's very complicated.

I know how to use xdebug to debug monolithic code but xdebug tends to follow the rabbit down the hole and hits the wall when it comes to a cURL call to a service.

Is there any way to "jump the gap" so to speak by intercepting the cURL call and starting xdebug on the service being called and having xdebug do the call, debug that service and then come back to the main service with the results?

Comment: You have to pass some xdebug flag (a cookie or GET/POST parameter) that would tell xdebug to debug that request as well. Obviously, for this you will have to modify your code (to add extra request parameter or cookie). So the alternative is to use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini -- this will tell xdebug to attempt to debug **every single request**. Such approach could be undesirable in no-need-to-debug-now moments ... but that's the only reliable way (AFAIK). Obviously, you also need some debug client (editor/IDE/whatever) that would support multiple debug sessions.

Comment: Check the "Communication setup" from [official docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) to have the idea (in case if you need such clarification, of course). P.S. Another alternative is to (yet again) edit your code .. but this time your "microservice" code -- add `xdebug_break();` -- a programmatic breakpoint -- should also trigger xdebug session.